# Jhipster - 404 error on app.js when running in prod profile

Tags: javascript, gulp, jhipster

I have a problem running my jhipster application in prod. After the deployment of prod war file the site is unable to load due to a 404 not found on /app/app.js
However vendor js and css are correctly injected. Not sure what's causing this issue.

Error message :

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
>   generated.js:19530
>
> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'module' of undefined(…)
>   http://localhost:9080/app/app.js
>
> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Error as seen in the browser's console:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

did you also build your app for prod? it looks like your app did not build the client site. This is done actually wiht the gulp build command. Depending on your build system maven or gradle you can specify the prod environment for the build phase, e.g. for maven ***mvn -Pprod package***.

The ***gulp build*** command will be automatically executed durring the build phase. In the [doc](https://jhipster.github.io/production/) you can find more information about how to use JHipster in production.

Comment: Thank you for the response. We found out that gulp build was also not working because of a problem that went undetected during development.

We had given "$" directly in HTML and that caused gulp build to fail. When we encoded, the problem was solved.