# Request cannot be processed when building JHipster application in prod profile

Tags: maven, spring-boot, gulp, jhipster

I'm using [jhipster](http://127.0.0.1:8080) to develop and deploy my webapp. By now I'm having a issue when building it (I'm using `maven`) in prod profile. When I access the URL i get the following:
[image]

When i build and run it in dev profile, all works fine.
According to `jhipster` docs, whats different between the profiles is that in `prod` it:

1. Generating an optimized JavaScript application with `Gulp`
2. GZipping With the "production" profile, JHipster configures a
       Servlet filter that applies gzip compression on your resources.
3. Cache headers With the "production" profile, JHipster configures a
       Servlet filter that puts specific HTTP cache headers on your static
       resources (JavaScript, CSS, fonts...) so they are cached by browsers and proxies.

I think it has something to do with the gulp build, but I'm really newbie with `gulp`, so I take suggestions.

Thanks

Comment: You should paste the errors you see in browser's console to show which requests fail

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40541270/jhipster-404-error-on-app-js-when-running-in-prod-profile/

Comment: Gaël, There's nothing in the console..

Comment: How are you running the `prod` version of the app?  Are there any errors in your app's log?  Make sure the prod database is set up and running

Comment: @JonRuddell There are no errors or warnings in the log. The API endpoints are working fine as well, so its just a frontend problem.

Comment: what is the url that are you trying to access?

Comment: Try running `gulp build` which builds the frontend for prod. If there are any errors in that process it should fail and give you an error message.  These are normally silent in the mvn packaging process

Comment: gulp build gives no erros, and I'm running localhost:8080

Comment: any help,im also getting the same issue !!

Answer (score 0):

Topic is a little bit older but I could get it work for me:
Step 1 make the javascript loading async

```
 <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" async>
```

step 2 enabling CORS config in the application.yaml

```
    cors:
    allowed-origins: "*"
    allowed-methods: "*"
    allowed-headers: "*"
    exposed-headers: "Authorization,Link,X-Total-Count"
    allow-credentials: true
    max-age: 1800
```

after that build your jhipster app with

```
mvnw package -Pprod verify
```